# How to Color Polygons in Esri Shapes

Tags: javascript, maps, arcgis, esri, arcgis-server

Hi I have a Esri Map in Shape format divided into different sub regions (polygons). I wanted to  access and select specific polygons using their  Latitude and longitude vales and wanted to color it .  Can anyone provide me the Code Esri Javascript API ?

Regards,
Vimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to push your shape on ArcGIS Online, there is a cheap developper access account fee to do it.

Then, here is the link in javascript to render polygons in several colors based on an attribute (ID, or whatever), using a Renderer 
[Using a UniqueValueRenderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/renderer_unique_value.html)

for getting the polygons on which apply the colors by a spatial query, you can use this technique : [Using a Query from FeatureLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/fl_paging.html)

Comment: this answer was not helpful. The topic of the question was not only off-topic, placing the answer here did only motivate the OP to post a follow-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575481/unable-to-connect-to-arcgis-online - So literally -1